# Pyside6 Qpainter.drawText() Make text wrap

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside6

I have a program that draws different sized rectangles and writes text in each rectangle (size and text can change)

I'd like the text to wrap whenever it does not fit inside the rectangle. As you can see in my code, I am center aligning it, and from what I've read I need to use `QTextOption.WrapMode.WordWrap`, but I don't know how to include it properly. Thank you for your help!

```
rectangle = QRect(self.startX, self.startY, int(self.Width),int(self.Length))
painter.fillRect(rectangle,self.colorList[i])
painter.drawText(rectangle,Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, self.AssiName[i])
painter.drawRect(rectangle)
```

As you can see startX, startY, Width, and Length are calculated in another part of the code. There are also color and assignment name lists that determine the color and text written inside. This is ran through a for loop to draw multiple rectangles with different text

I have modified the drawText line of code to be:
`painter.drawText(rectangle, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter | QTextOption.WrapMode.WordWrap, self.AssName[i])`

but that crashes the program.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong. To get the text to wrap use this:

```
painter.drawText(rectangle,Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter|Qt.TextFlag.TextWordWrap, self.AssName[i])
```

As you can see, I just needed to add `QT.TextFlag.TextWordWrapenter`